# AttributeError: module has no attribute 'RegisterShape'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using TensorFlow 1.14 version and python 3.6.
I got the error as follow :

```
"AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops' has no attribute 'RegisterShape'"

This is my source code :

ops.RegisterShape("ZeroInitializer")(None)

    def _InitOpDefLibrary(op_list_proto_bytes):
      op_list = _op_def_pb2.OpList()
      op_list.ParseFromString(op_list_proto_bytes)
      _op_def_registry.register_op_list(op_list)
      op_def_lib = _op_def_library.OpDefLibrary()
      op_def_lib.add_op_list(op_list)
      return op_def_lib
```

i am working in Ubuntu, and unable to create/register operation in C++

Comment: Shape functions for core ops were moved to C++ via REGISTER_OP(...).SetShapeFn(...). So you may have to first create/register your operation in C++. Full guide can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/create_op)