# Tensorflow migration problem regardless defining the operations tensorflow.python.framework.ops

Tags: python, tensorflow, migration

I am running [a model from github](https://github.com/wentaoyuan/pcn) and I already encountered several errors with pathing etc. After fixing this, I think the main error for now is tensorflow. This repo was probably done when TF 1.x, and now with the change to TF 2, I might need to migrate everything.

Mainly, I get the following error:

```
    @ops.RegisterShape('ApproxMatch')
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops' has no attribute 'RegisterShape'
```

in:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
import os.path as osp

base_dir = osp.dirname(osp.abspath(__file__))

approxmatch_module = tf.load_op_library(osp.join(base_dir, 'tf_approxmatch_so.so'))


def approx_match(xyz1,xyz2):
    '''
input:
    xyz1 : batch_size * #dataset_points * 3
    xyz2 : batch_size * #query_points * 3
returns:
    match : batch_size * #query_points * #dataset_points
    '''
    return approxmatch_module.approx_match(xyz1,xyz2)
ops.NoGradient('ApproxMatch')
#@tf.RegisterShape('ApproxMatch')
@ops.RegisterShape('ApproxMatch')
def _approx_match_shape(op):
    shape1=op.inputs[0].get_shape().with_rank(3)
    shape2=op.inputs[1].get_shape().with_rank(3)
    return [tf.TensorShape([shape1.dims[0],shape2.dims[1],shape1.dims[1]])]
```

2 main things I am not understanding:

1. I read that this probably will make me have to create the `ops` [C++ routines](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/create_op) but at the same time, I can see that these are done in here: `@ops.RegisterShape('ApproxMatch')` . [Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59043649/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-python-framework-ops-has-no-attribute-regis) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59643248/attributeerror-module-has-no-attribute-registershape)  with `REGISTER_OP(...).SetShapeFn(...)`. But I dont think I am understanding the process and have seen other questions with the same, but no real implementation/answer.
2. If I go to the location of the tf_approxmatch shared library ( `approxmatch_module = tf.load_op_library(osp.join(base_dir, 'tf_approxmatch_so.so'))` ), I cannot open it or edit it with `gedit`, so I am assuming I am not supposed to change anything in there (?).

There are `py`, `cpp` and `cu` files in that folder (I already did `make` yesterday and everything ran smoothly).

```
__init__.py     tf_approxmatch.cu.o   tf_nndistance.cu.o
makefile        tf_approxmatch.py     tf_nndistance.py
__pycache__     tf_approxmatch_so.so  tf_nndistance_so.so
tf_approxmatch.cpp  tf_nndistance.cpp
tf_approxmatch.cu   tf_nndistance.cu
```

My main guess is that I should register the operation of RegisterShape somehow in the cpp file as it already has some registered ops, but I am a bit lost because **I am not even sure if I am understanding the problem I have**. I will just show the first lines of the file:

```
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
using namespace tensorflow;
REGISTER_OP("ApproxMatch")
    .Input("xyz1: float32")
    .Input("xyz2: float32")
    .Output("match: float32");
REGISTER_OP("MatchCost")
    .Input("xyz1: float32")
    .Input("xyz2: float32")
    .Input("match: float32")
    .Output("cost: float32");
REGISTER_OP("MatchCostGrad")
    .Input("xyz1: float32")
    .Input("xyz2: float32")
    .Input("match: float32")
    .Output("grad1: float32")
    .Output("grad2: float32");
```

Comment: Shape functions for core ops were moved to C++ via REGISTER_OP(...).SetShapeFn(...). So you may have to first create/register your operation in C++. For more details [refer](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/create_op). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: Unless no other choice, I would strongly recommend sticking to TensorFlow 1.x. Migrating code from TF 1.x to 2.x can be incredibly time consuming.

---

Registering a shape is done in c++ using `SetShapeFn` and not in python since TF 1.0. However, the private python API was kept in TF 1.x (I presume for backward compatibility reasons), but was completely removed in TF 2.0.

The [Create an Op](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/create_op) guide is really useful to migrate the code in that case, and I would really recommend reading it.

First of all, why is it needed to register a shape? It's needed for shape inference, a feature that allow TensorFlow to know the shape of the inputs and outputs in the computation graph without running actual code. Shape Inference allows, for example, error handling when trying to use an op on Tensors that don't have a compatible shape.

In your specific case, you need to convert the python code that uses `ops.RegisterShape` to c++ code using `SetShapeFn`. Thankfully, the github repository you are working with provides comments that are going to be helpful.

Let's start with the `approx_match` function. The python code is the following:

```
def approx_match(xyz1,xyz2):
    '''
input:
    xyz1 : batch_size * #dataset_points * 3
    xyz2 : batch_size * #query_points * 3
returns:
    match : batch_size * #query_points * #dataset_points
    '''
    return approxmatch_module.approx_match(xyz1,xyz2)
@ops.RegisterShape('ApproxMatch')
def _approx_match_shape(op):
    shape1=op.inputs[0].get_shape().with_rank(3)
    shape2=op.inputs[1].get_shape().with_rank(3)
    return [tf.TensorShape([shape1.dims[0],shape2.dims[1],shape1.dims[1]])]
```

Reading the code and the comments, we understand the following:

- There is 2 inputs `xyz1`, and `xyz2`
- `xyz1` has the shape `(batch_size, dataset_points, 3)`
- `xyz2` has the shape `(batch_size, query_points, 3)`
- There is 1 output: `match`
- `match` has the shape `(batch_size, query_points, dataset_points)`

This would translate to the following C++ code:

```cpp
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/shape_inference.h"
using namespace tensorflow;
REGISTER_OP("ApproxMatch")
    .Input("xyz1: float32")
    .Input("xyz2: float32")
    .Output("match: float32")
    .SetShapeFn([](shape_inference::InferenceContext* c) {
        shape_inference::ShapeHandle xyz1_shape = c->input(0);
        shape_inference::ShapeHandle xyz2_shape = c->input(1);
        // batch_size is the first dimension 
        shape_inference::DimensionHandle batch_size = c->Dim(xyz1_shape, 0);
        // dataset_points points is the 2nd dimension of the first input
        shape_inference::DimensionHandle dataset_points = c->Dim(xyz1_shape, 1);
        // query_points points is the 2nd dimension of the second input
        shape_inference::DimensionHandle query_points = c->Dim(xyz2_shape, 1);
        // Creating the new shape (batch_size, query_points, dataset_points)
        // and setting it to the output
        c->set_output(0, c->MakeShape({batch_size, query_points, dataset_points})); 
        // Returning a status telling that everything went well
        return Status::OK();    
    });
```

**Warning**: This code does not contain any error handling (for example, checking that the first dimensions of the 2 inputs are the same, or that the last dimension of both inputs is 3). I let that as an exercise to the reader, you could look at the aforementioned guide or directly to the [source code of some ops](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.8.0/tensorflow/core/ops/math_ops.cc) to have an idea on how to do error handling, with, for example, the macro `TF_RETURN_IF_ERROR`.

---

The same steps can be applied to the `match_cost` function, which could look like that:

```cpp
REGISTER_OP("MatchCost")
    .Input("xyz1: float32")
    .Input("xyz2: float32")
    .Input("match: float32")
    .Output("cost: float32")
    .SetShapeFn([](shape_inference::InferenceContext* c) {
        shape_inference::DimensionHandle batch_size = c->Dim(c->input(0), 0);
        c->set_output(0, c->Vector(batch_size));
        return Status::OK();        
    });
```

---

You need then to recompile the `so` library with the makefile included in the project. You might have to change some flags, for example, TF 2.8 uses the c++ standard c++14 instead of c++11, so the flag `-std=c++14` is needed. Once the library is compiled, you can test importing it in python:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> approxmatch_module = tf.load_op_library('./tf_approxmatch_so.so')
>>> a = tf.random.uniform((10,20,3))
>>> b = tf.random.uniform((10,50,3))
>>> c = approxmatch_module.approx_match(a,b)
>>> c.shape
TensorShape([10, 50, 20])
```

Comment: Edited my code, compiled it, and the make worked like a charm, but the error now is probably due to problems with CUDA, cudnn and TF compatibilities. `undefined symbol: _ZN10tensorflow8OpKernel11TraceStringB5cxx11EPNS_15OpKernelContextEb
`
 I just can't find the proper way to install the versions the author use, due to the conda channels. I think these versions are not available. Maybe in regular PIP (doubt it though), but not anaconda at least. But thank you!

Answer (score -1):

according to tensorflow's release log, `RegisterShape` is deprecated, and you should use `SetShapeFn` to define the shape when registering your operator in c++ source file.

Comment: I found that information before posting the question, and I have seen several questions with the same answers/comments as yours! `SetShapeFn`, as well as a guide (which for me is a bit confusing) onto how implement and register those operators in c++ source files. But no implementations nor more easily understandable guides have been posted anywhere from my understanding and research. That is the reason for my question.